# use \boldsymbol for all math expression

Tags: boldsymbol

(a) Is there a way to enforce \boldsymbol for all math expression? I know that I can use e.g. \newcommand  but I wonder if there is a way to enforce this globally.

(b) What possible issues might this case? (e.g. conflict with specific fonts?)  I vaguely recall that there were rare occasions where \boldsymbol does not work and I have use to \mathbb, or something like that (but it's been a while so I could be mistaken).

THANKS!

Comment: I would not recommend it but you can use `\boldmath`. `\documentclass{article}
\boldmath
\begin{document}
$E=mc^2$    
\end{document}`

Comment: do not use `\boldsymbol` use `\boldmath` as IanC says

Comment: Thanks!  Putting \boldmath at the start of the document works, but the slash in $\not=$ seem to be off.   I off course could adjust the slash one at a time; is there a way to fix that once and for all?  In case that matters, I use mathpazo in conjunction with eulervm, and the slash problem seems to stem from eulervm.  THANKS!